# Makefile: for each file ending in .abc perform an action to create target .xyz

Tags: makefile

Can you write a makefile which for each existing file ending in .abc produces a file .xyz according to some given rule? Something to summarize

```
t1.xyz : s1.abc
    touch t1.xyz; s1.abc > t1.xyz

t2.xyz : s2.abc
    touch t2.xyz; s2.abc > t2.xyz

t3.xyz : s3.abc
    touch t3.xyz; s3.abc > t3.xyz
```

It would be great if that pattern could be manually overwritten for a specific target/source if the need arises.

Comment: Does `s1.abc > t1.xyz` work in your shell?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this in stages. We start with (something like) your makefile:

```
t1.xyz : s1.abc
    do_something s1.abc > t1.xyz

t2.xyz : s2.abc
    do_something s2.abc > t2.xyz

t3.xyz : s3.abc
    do_something s3.abc > t3.xyz
```

Then we use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to remove some of the redundancy:

```
t1.xyz : s1.abc
    do_something $^ > $@

t2.xyz : s2.abc
    do_something $^ > $@

t3.xyz : s3.abc
    do_something $^ > $@
```

We notice that these recipes are all the same, so we replace the rules with one [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
t%.xyz : s%.abc
    do_something $^ > $@
```

Then we can add some more features:

```
SOME_TARGETS:= t1.xyz t2.xyz t3.xyz
SOME_SPECIAL_TARGETS:= t4.xyz t5.xyz
ALL_POSSIBLE_TARGETS:= $(patsubst s%.abc,t%.xyz,$(wildcard s*.abc))

all: $(ALL_POSSIBLE_TARGETS)

t%.xyz : s%.abc
    do_something $^ > $@

# this overrides the pattern rule for a specific target
t7.xyz : s7.abc
    do_something_special $^ > $@

# this overrides the pattern rule for a list of targets
$(SOME_SPECIAL_TARGETS): t%.xyz : s%.abc
    do_something_special $^ > $@
```

A little more polishing is possible, but this should keep you busy for a while.